# document.getElementsByTagName() returns wrong element

Tags: javascript, html, xml, html-table, getelementsbytagname

I'm quite new to HTML, JavaScript and XML (in the context of the previous two) so have that in mind. I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<university
    xmlns="myNS:university"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="myNS university.xsd">
    <students>
        <student sid="jdoe12345>
            <lastname>Doe</lastname>
            <firstname>John</lastname>
            <courses>
                <course cid="MB100">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="W10" type="simple">5.0</grade>
                    <grade attempt="2" term="S11" type="simple">2.3</grade>
                </course>
                <course cid="MB110">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="S11" type="complex">2.0</grade>
                    <course cid="MB111">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="S11" type="simple">1.0</grade>
                    </course>
                    <course cid="MB112">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="S11" type="simple">5.0</grade>
                        <grade attempt="2" term="S11" type="simple">3.0</grade>
                    </course>
                </course>
                ...
            </courses>
        </student>
        ...
    </students>
</university>
```

I'll try to explain what the structure is as short as possible: The top element is "university" and it contains a single child "students". "students" on the other hand can contain multiple "student" elements, each with a unique student identification "sid" as attribute, "lastname" element, "firstname" element and an element "courses" which contains all courses (each represented by the "course" element" the student has attended. A "course" element has also a unique identification, which either represents a single course (example above: MB111,MB112) or a module (example above: MB100, MB110). Another element that "course" contains is the "grade" element, which can be two type - "simple" and "complex". Multiple attempts are available and each attempt is evaluated with a grade (example above: for MB100 we have two attempts). The simple grade is used for a module consisting of a single course (example above: MB100). The complex grade on the other hand is the arithmetic mean of all simple grades of each course a module consists of taking the highest grade of all attempts for a single course (example above: the MB110 has a grade = 2.0, which is the arithmetic mean of 1.0 and 3.0 for each of the courses it consists of with 3.0 being the attempts with a highest grade for the course MB112).

That said I want to create an HTML page and generate a table using JavaScript with all students in it. Currently I'm trying to display the "sid" attribute of each "student" element plus his/her first and last name. My page source code looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My pretty page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","/home/USERNAME/xmlplayground/university.xml",false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            document.write("<table border='1'>");
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("*","student");
            for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                document.write("<tr><td>");
                document.write(x[i].getAttribute("sid"));
                document.write("</td><td>");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("*","lastname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("</td><td>");
                document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("*","firstname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("</td></tr>");
            }
            document.write("</table>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason I get a very weird output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| null | 5.0 --------------------------------------------------------^ | 5.0 --------------------------------------------------------^ |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| null |                 EMPTY CELL HERE!!!                            |                      NO CELL HERE!!!
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using Iceweasel's (Firefox in Debian) debugger I've noticed that the x variable has 2 children both of which give an InnerHTML error:

```
"XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///home/USERNAME/xmlplayground/university.xml
Line Number 12, Column 57:
<sourcetext xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml">
                    &lt;grade attempt="1" term="WS10" type=simple&gt;5.0&lt;/grade&gt;--------------------------------------------------------^
</sourcetext>"
```

Also I have to mention that I'm using Oxygen XML Editor, which so far has proven to be very buggy (for working with XSD, DTD and XSLT not to mention its almost non-existent support for JavaScript editing) but I'm more or less forced to use it. The problem though looks more related to what I have personally written.

Comment: The `.getElementsByTagName()` function just takes 1 argument.

Comment: You are right. When I removed it though I get nothing at all. Debugger says that x has length = 0. :-/

Comment: Hm, `<grade attempt="1" term="WS10" type=simple>5.0</grade>` *is* not well-formed (missing quotes around the `type` attribute's value).

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo while I was writing my code here on Stackoverflow. Will edit it.

Comment: Hmmm, strange. This is the debug message you were referring to. However I do have the quotes there in the original XML file.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, you have closed your `firstname` tag wrong, it should be closed with `</firstname>` instead of `</lastname>`. :P

Apply this JS:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/home/USERNAME/xmlplayground/university.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("student");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getAttribute("sid"));
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("lastname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

And here's your fixed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<university
    xmlns="myNS:university"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="myNS university.xsd">
    <students>
        <student sid="jdoe12345">
            <lastname>Doe</lastname>
            <firstname>John</firstname>
            <courses>
                <course cid="MB100">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="W10" type="simple">5.0</grade>
                    <grade attempt="2" term="S11" type="simple">2.3</grade>
                </course>
                <course cid="MB110">
                    <grade attempt="1" term="S11" type="complex">2.0</grade>
                    <course cid="MB111">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="S11" type="simple">1.0</grade>
                    </course>
                    <course cid="MB112">
                        <grade attempt="1" term="S11" type="simple">5.0</grade>
                        <grade attempt="2" term="S11" type="simple">3.0</grade>
                    </course>
                </course>
            </courses>
        </student>
    </students>
</university>
```

Comment: I've changed this in my original document as suggested by @Pointy. See my comment below my question.

Comment: Any messages now in the console?

Comment: Yes, after making some changes it seem that my XML is not well-formed. In the console the message "not well-formed" linking to my university.xml file is displayed. I'll check it and see where the problem appears. Oxygen XML seems to give me some very confusing error messages concerning my XML file in particular about "course" and "cid". On one hand it say that "Attribute '{myNS:university}cid' must appear on element 'course'" but on the other it says "Attribute 'cid' is not allowed to appear in element 'course'"???

Comment: Slowly getting to the source of my problems. About the quotes I just looked closely and it seems that Oxygen XML editor inserted ” instead of " for some unknown reason. Naturally ” is not recognized as a valid quote character in the XML element.

Comment: I think you are not able to nest `course` within a `course`. Change the name of the nested one and see if that works. :)

Comment: Hmm, nope, that should not be a problem since I have explicitly states in my XSD that "course" can contain 0 or more "course" elements using a recursive reference to the "course" definition.

Comment: @rbaleksandar copy the XML from my last XML and check if it works.

Comment: I did exactly those changes. It's my cid and sid that ruin everything for some reason. I'm currently checking my XSD to see what I did wrong.

Comment: Yes, now it is working. I found a couple more of the weird quotation characters. I have no idea why Oxygen did that. I used its autocomplete feature. I'm still getting validation errors in Oxygen XML editor concerning my cid and sid attributes though. Xmllint also returns errors there so it's not an Oxygen thing only. Thanks a lot for your help! Will mark your reply as the answer since it actually pointed me to the right direction. Copying it revealed to me the problem with the characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63240/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-rbaleksandar).